# Is a Tax question/wiki appropriate?

Tags: discussion, topic, questions

Is there any concern about liability if I were to post a wiki-question where we could consolidate sourced guidance on crypto tax policy from around the world?

Answer (score 3):

This seems within the realm of reason, and I'd cautiously say "yes."

I could see it being relevant for software architectural reasons--picture, a year or two in the future, some country saying that income to a DAO is income to the token holders. This would be important to know!

That said, this is ignoring whether it'd be some source of liability--does stackexchange in general have a policy on this? (To be fair, there's already plenty sources of liability elsewhere. Consider the money and personal finance stack exchange.)